# DBContext DBSet query and the no tracking option

Tags: entity-framework

Based on other posts such as [Entity Framework and DbContext - Object Tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099134/entity-framework-and-dbcontext-object-tracking)
it would appear the simplified DBContext interface doesnt expose the to set No tracking on basic queries.
A little blog showing how with Object context
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/02/20/disabling-change-tracking-in-entity-framework.aspx

What is a good approach to loading results via the DbContext as not tracked?
How are the performance conscious doing this if using Dbcontext ?
ie have base GetList method I would like to improve for performance reasons.

```
public DbSet<T> EntityDbSet { get { return _context.Set<T>(); } }
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
         return EntityDbSet.Where(predicate);
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [AsNoTracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.asnotracking%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is an extension on IQueryable.

You can update your function above with:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
         return EntityDbSet.Where(predicate).AsNoTracking();
    }
```

Comment: Works a treat. Here i am convinced it wasnt exposed on dbset.  I was looking for wrong option. thanks Mark

Comment: Please also note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502572/how-do-i-turn-off-change-tracking-at-the-dbcontext-level-in-ef-4-1-rc